# Chrome tab font too small

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, fonts

[image: http://puu.sh/kzA9n/0bc3275cc0.png]

I'm having this weird problem with chrome since this sunday. As you can see from the image, my bookmark and tab font are insanely small, does anyone have any clue why?

I tried googling for this but nothing worked. I'm on Windows 10 by the way, font size set to 100%.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to leave an answer, but a quick fix is to right click the shortcut and add at the end `--force-device-scale-factor=1.5` or whatever number you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see in your screenshot, Chrome has switched to a different typeface (different from Segoe UI) to render the labels. So, I conclude you are affected by [issue 531265](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=531265), which is currently under investigation.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, I guess I'm not alone.

Comment: @SorinLascu Feel free to mark it as accepted then =)

Answer (score 6):

Right click on your desktop and click Display Settings.

[image: Display Settings Dialog]

Then drag the slider to the right a bit until the text is to your liking.

[image: change the size of apps text and other items on the screen]

I had this issue on my Macbook Pro's bootcamp partition.

Comment: That setting, while it does increases font in Chrome, it also increases it in everything else.

Answer (score -1):

Go into chrome://settings

Press 'Show Advanced'

Find this:

[image: Web Content Settings]

Change it to something that looks good.

Comment: As you can tell by the “Web content” label, this setting does not apply to Chrome’s user interface.

Comment: @Fitoschido well hopefully this will be a help to someone else then.

Comment: It isn't. TheQ is here because this doesn't work for bookmarks and tabs.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar "freaky"problem happen to me when I was tidying up my bookmarks bar on Windows 7. The font was the usual size at first then all of a sudden the font size shrunk before my eyes. All I'd been doing was highlighting and selecting text to delete bookmarks. I clicked out of the bookmarks page - everything else was okay. I clicked on the three bars symbol in the top right hand corner (if you hover over it, it says customize and control google chrome).  I Left clicked and read down the list - it said zoom 100% so I thought everything was okay. But when I clicked on text just on the bookmarks bar page it said zoom was 50%.  I changed it back to zoom 100% and the bookmarks bar and text displayed normally again. Why did it happen?  I read on a different site that if you accidentally press control when your cursor is pointed at a font it can change the size or type of font on that page. Maybe this has happened to you.

Comment: this should be a comment as it doesn't contain a definitive answer